# how to get column, row number based on value in matrix from numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How to return column and row number based on value in matrix?

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.randint(9, size=(3,3))
#matrix
#[[2 3 3]
# [6 2 4]
# [1 8 4]]
```

something like

```
matrix.where(2,[]) => (0,0), (1,1)
matrix.where(4,[]) => (1,2), (2,2)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(0, 0), (1, 1)` for 2?

Comment: yes. my bad. updated

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.argwhere` function

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.randint(9, size=(3,3))
print(matrix)
# array([[2, 1, 3],
#        [7, 2, 4],
#        [1, 7, 7]])

np.argwhere(matrix == 7)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Note that `argwhere` is just `np.transpose(np.where(...))` - an alternative presentation of the `where` information.

Comment: For matrix or multidimensional array `np.argwhere`  output is more readable than `np.where`

Comment: The argwhere version is also easier to use iteratively.  But to access all values with one operation, the where tuple is better.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function.

```
matrix = np.random.randint(9, size=(3,3))
np.where(matrix == 2)
```

Comment: You obtain the result in a zip way, argwhere is better I think.